# Keener Lemma 9.1 proof

Tags: probability-theory, random-functions

I'm reading the book Theoretical Statistics by Keener, and I couldn't figure out one of the claims in the proof for Lemma 9.1.

Lemma 9.1 states: let $W$ be a random function in $C(K)$ where $K \subset \mathbb{R}^p$ is compact. Define $\mu(t)=EW(t)$, $t \in K$ to be the mean of $W$. If $E ||W||_{\infty} < \infty$, then $\mu$ is continuous. Also, define $M_\epsilon(t) = \sup_{s:||s-t||<\epsilon} |W(s)-W(t)|$, then

$$\sup_{t \in K} E M_\epsilon(t) \to 0 \quad \text{as } \epsilon \to 0.$$

In the proof for the second claim, it's stated that:

1. $M_\epsilon$ is continuous because $W$ is continuous.
2. By continuity, $M_\epsilon(t) \to 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Here's my understanding. The first statement says that for each $\epsilon>0$, $M_\epsilon$ is continuous in $t$. This is needed in the later part of the proof to show $\lambda_\epsilon = E M_\epsilon(t)$ is continuous. I don't know how to prove this statement, would appreciate any comments!!

The second statement says that for each $t$, $M_\epsilon(t)$ is continuous in $\epsilon$ at $\epsilon=0$. I can prove this using the fact that $W$ is uniformly continuous on $K$, thanks to the comment from @Mushu Nrek. Here's a sketch of the proof: I want to show for any positive sequence $\{\epsilon_n\}$ where $\epsilon_n \to 0$, $M_{\epsilon_n}(t) \to M_0(t)=0$. Now fix any $\gamma>0$, by uniform continuity of $W$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $M_\delta(t)<\gamma$. Find $N$ large such that $\epsilon_N < \delta$, now $|M_{\epsilon_n}(t)|<|M_{\epsilon_N}(t)|<\gamma$ for all $n>N$. Hence completing the proof.

Comment: You are on the right track, but it seems to me that your sentence is not in the best of orders. Instead, for a given $\delta$, you should be able to find an $\epsilon_0>0$ such that for all $0 < \epsilon < \epsilon_0$, you have $0\leq M_\epsilon(t) \leq \delta$. And this concludes the proof.

Comment: Thanks @MushuNrek! Yeah now I see how to prove this statement. I've updated my question accordingly. I realized that to complete the proof, I still need to show $M_\epsilon$ is continuous in $t$, but no idea how to show that ... any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Maybe, it is helpful to note that the supremum is actually attained in some $s_{t,\epsilon}$ as the function is continuous on a compact interval. Then, you can write that $\vert M_\epsilon(t) - M_\epsilon(r)\vert = \vert \vert W(s_{t,\epsilon}) - W(t)\vert - \vert W(s_{r,\epsilon}) - W(r)\vert\vert$ for which you can use the reverse triangular inequality.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply again! I've thought about it, but still don't see how I can bound this quantity. I can see that it's smaller than $|W(s_{t,\epsilon})-W(s_{r,\epsilon})|+|W(t)-W(r)|$. But from here I don't know how to use the fact that $t$ and $r$ are close to bound $|W(s_{t,\epsilon})-W(s_{r,\epsilon})|$...

Comment: Can you give an interval in which $s_{t,\epsilon}$ will certainly be in?

Comment: $s_{t,\epsilon}$ will be in $\bar{B}_{\epsilon}(t)$, the $\epsilon$ radius closed ball centered at $t$, where $\epsilon$ is pre-fixed and I cannot change. If $|t-r|<\delta$, the distance between $s_{t,\epsilon}$ and $s_{r,\epsilon}$ is bounded by $2\epsilon+\delta$ by triangle inequality, which is not helpful ... So I think I need to make use of the fact that when $t$ and $t'$ are close, $s_{t,\epsilon}$ and $s_{r,\epsilon}$ have to be close. These are all I can think of ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there are two things.

First concerning the proof of the Lemma. I don't think that one needs to show that $M_\epsilon$ is continuous in $t$. Indeed, since $W$ is continuous on a compact, it is uniformly continuous. Therefore, independently of $t \in K$, there exists for every $\delta > 0$ some $\epsilon_0 > 0$ such that $M_\epsilon(t) < \delta$ for all $\epsilon < \epsilon_0$. In particular, $\sup_{t\in K} M_\epsilon(t) < \delta$. Then, the result follows by dominated convergence.

$\ $

But now answering your question: Why is $M_\epsilon$ continuous in $t$? Let $t_n \to t$ in $K$. Writing $B(r,\epsilon)$ for the ball around $r$ with radius $\epsilon$, we conclude that for every $s\in B(t,\epsilon)$, there exists some $s_n\in B(t_n, \epsilon)$ such that $\Vert s - s_n\Vert \leq \Vert t - t_n\Vert$. By the uniform continuity of $W$ on $K$, we may thus for every $\delta > 0$ choose $N$ large enough such that for every $n\geq N$, there is for every $s\in B(t, \epsilon)$ some $s_n\in B(t_n, \epsilon)$ with
$$
\vert W(s_n) - W(s)\vert < \delta.
$$
In particular,
$$
\vert W(s) - W(t)\vert \leq \vert W(s_n) - W(t_n)\vert + \vert W(s_n) - W(s)\vert + \vert W(t_n) - W(t)\vert
$$
(and similarly in the opposite direction) and therefore
$$
M_\epsilon(t_n) - 2\delta \leq M_\epsilon(t) \leq M_\epsilon(t_n) + 2\delta
$$
for all $n\geq N$. Since $\delta$ was arbitrary, this means that $M_\epsilon(t_n) \to M_\epsilon(t)$ as $n\to +\infty$.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply!! Now I can see how to prove $M_\epsilon$ is continuous. One technical thing I'm wondering is ... should it be $|M_\epsilon(t) -M_\epsilon(t_n)|<2\delta$ instead of $\delta$?

And I think you are right that the continuity of $M_\epsilon$ is not needed for the proof. I was following the proof in the book where I think the continuity of $M_\epsilon$ is used to get the continuity of $\lambda_\epsilon$. But I agree that continuity of $\lambda_\epsilon$ is not needed to show $\lambda_\epsilon(t) \to 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: @statstats you are completely right, I edited the answer!